# My computer cannot reach/ping a specific host but another computer can

Tags: networking, ip, traceroute

I have two computers X and Y that are connected to the same LAN. X has Ubuntu, Y has Windows 10. Both computers can reach sites like google, facebook, bing, etc. But there is a certain website, www.metu.edu.tr, to which Y can successfully connect but X cannot.

When I do traceroute from X, I get:

```
bash$ traceroute www.metu.edu.tr
traceroute to www.metu.edu.tr (144.122.145.151), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  ResNet-64-1.resnet.ucsb.edu (169.231.64.1)  1.701 ms  1.719 ms  1.930 ms
 2  128.111.174.1 (128.111.174.1)  12.325 ms  12.356 ms  12.547 ms
 3  lax-hpr3--ucsb-100ge.cenic.net.cenic.net (137.164.26.237)  3.981 ms  4.756 ms  5.586 ms
 4  137.164.26.201 (137.164.26.201)  4.894 ms  5.756 ms  6.636 ms
 5  et-1-0-0.111.rtr.hous.net.internet2.edu (198.71.45.20)  37.414 ms  37.669 ms  37.418 ms
 6  et-10-0-0.105.rtr.atla.net.internet2.edu (198.71.45.12)  61.083 ms  61.577 ms  61.338 ms
 7  et-9-0-0.104.rtr.wash.net.internet2.edu (198.71.45.7)  75.429 ms  75.788 ms  74.937 ms
 8  internet2.mx1.fra.de.geant.net (62.40.125.17)  183.994 ms  174.990 ms  183.220 ms
 9  ulakbim-bckp-gw.mx1.fra.de.geant.net (62.40.125.154)  208.499 ms  198.691 ms  198.609 ms
10  193.140.0.149 (193.140.0.149)  201.010 ms  204.371 ms  201.153 ms
11  193.140.85.138 (193.140.85.138)  262.353 ms  248.916 ms  248.477 ms
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

The last IP (at step 11) is not www.metu.edu.tr's IP. When I try to connect using the browser, connection times out.

But the computer Y which is in the same LAN as X, can connect www.metu.edu.tr.

Any ideas on how can fix the problem or further diagnose it?

Answer (score 0):

A failed traceroute does not mean that there is anything wrong with your Computer X. Did you try a traceroute (tracert) in Computer Y (Windows)? I did, and it failed even though I can get to the www.metu.edu.tr without any issue.

I also could not ping www.metu.edu.tr successfully even though it loads fine in the browser.

Websites can detect the user agent and can decide to ignore or not render when you access the site using a particular browser. Can you try navigating to the site using a different browser under Computer X?

Comment: Different browsers don't work either. I'm actually trying to ssh to a computer at metu.edu.tr domain but the ssh command times out after a long time without asking any passwords. Another computer in the same LAN can successfully ssh to the server at metu.edu.tr.

Comment: Note: X's IP is not banned at the server.